# Dynamic programming knapsack solution

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I wrote a solution to the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) in Python, using a bottom-up dynamic programming algorithm. It correctly computes the optimal value, given a list of items with values and weights, and a maximum allowed weight.

Any critique on code style, comment style, readability, and best-practice would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure how Pythonic the code is; filling in a matrix seems like a natural way of implementing dynamic programming, but it doesn't "feel" Pythonic (and is that a bad thing, in this case?).

Note that the comments are a little on the verbose side; as I was writing the algorithm, I tried to be as explicit about each step as possible, since I was trying to understand it to the fullest extent possible. If they are excessive (or just plain incorrect), feel free to comment (hah!) on it.

```
import sys

def knapsack(items, maxweight):
    # Create an (N+1) by (W+1) 2-d list to contain the running values
    # which are to be filled by the dynamic programming routine.
    #
    # There are N+1 rows because we need to account for the possibility
    # of choosing from 0 up to and including N possible items.
    # There are W+1 columns because we need to account for possible
    # "running capacities" from 0 up to and including the maximum weight W.
    bestvalues = [[0] * (maxweight + 1)
                  for i in xrange(len(items) + 1)]

    # Enumerate through the items and fill in the best-value table
    for i, (value, weight) in enumerate(items):
        # Increment i, because the first row (0) is the case where no items
        # are chosen, and is already initialized as 0, so we're skipping it
        i += 1
        for capacity in xrange(maxweight + 1):
            # Handle the case where the weight of the current item is greater
            # than the "running capacity" - we can't add it to the knapsack
            if weight > capacity:
                bestvalues[i][capacity] = bestvalues[i - 1][capacity]
            else:
                # Otherwise, we must choose between two possible candidate values:
                # 1) the value of "running capacity" as it stands with the last item
                #    that was computed; if this is larger, then we skip the current item
                # 2) the value of the current item plus the value of a previously computed
                #    set of items, constrained by the amount of capacity that would be left
                #    in the knapsack (running capacity - item's weight)
                candidate1 = bestvalues[i - 1][capacity]
                candidate2 = bestvalues[i - 1][capacity - weight] + value

                # Just take the maximum of the two candidates; by doing this, we are
                # in effect "setting in stone" the best value so far for a particular
                # prefix of the items, and for a particular "prefix" of knapsack capacities
                bestvalues[i][capacity] = max(candidate1, candidate2)

    # Reconstruction
    # Iterate through the values table, and check
    # to see which of the two candidates were chosen. We can do this by simply
    # checking if the value is the same as the value of the previous row. If so, then
    # we say that the item was not included in the knapsack (this is how we arbitrarily
    # break ties) and simply move the pointer to the previous row. Otherwise, we add
    # the item to the reconstruction list and subtract the item's weight from the
    # remaining capacity of the knapsack. Once we reach row 0, we're done
    reconstruction = []
    i = len(items)
    j = maxweight
    while i > 0:
        if bestvalues[i][j] != bestvalues[i - 1][j]:
            reconstruction.append(items[i - 1])
            j -= items[i - 1][1]
        i -= 1

    # Reverse the reconstruction list, so that it is presented
    # in the order that it was given
    reconstruction.reverse()

    # Return the best value, and the reconstruction list
    return bestvalues[len(items)][maxweight], reconstruction


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('usage: knapsack.py [file]')
        sys.exit(1)

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    maxweight = int(lines[0])
    items = [map(int, line.split()) for line in lines[1:]]

    bestvalue, reconstruction = knapsack(items, maxweight)

    print('Best possible value: {0}'.format(bestvalue))
    print('Items:')
    for value, weight in reconstruction:
        print('V: {0}, W: {1}'.format(value, weight))
```

The input file that it expects is as follows:

```
165
92 23
57 31
49 29
68 44
60 53
43 38
67 63
84 85
87 89
72 82
```

The first line contains the maximum weight allowed, and subsequent lines contain the items, represented by value-weight pairs.

Comment: An old post, I know, but if you haven't run into it already `enumerate` allows you to specify the starting index (e.g. `for i,item in enumerate(items,1):` would have `i` begin at 1.

Comment: @SimonT: Fantastic! I've programmed in Python for 2+ years now, and I had never seen `enumerate` used that way. I'll definitely keep it in mind.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. The function `knapsack` lacks a docstring that would explain what arguments the function takes (what kind of things are in `items`? must `items` be a sequence, or can it be an iterable?) and what it returns.
2. This kind of function is ideal for [doctests](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).
3. The comments say things like "Create an (N+1) by (W+1) 2-d list". But what is N and what is W? Presumably N is `len(items)` and W is `maxweight`, so it would be a good idea to use the same names in the comments and the code:

   ```
   N = len(items)
   W = maxweight
   ```
4. The comment above `bestvalues` fails to explain what the values in this table mean. I would write something like this:

   ```
   # bestvalues[i][j] is the best sum of values for any
   # subsequence of the first i items, whose weights sum
   # to no more than j.
   ```

   This makes it obvious why \$0 ≤ i ≤ N\$ and why \$0 ≤ j ≤ W\$.
5. In a loop like:

   ```
   bestvalues = [[0] * (maxweight + 1)
                 for i in xrange(len(items) + 1)]
   ```

   where the loop variable (here `i`) is unused, it's conventional to name it `_`.
6. These lines could be omitted:

   ```
   # Increment i, because the first row (0) is the case where no items
   # are chosen, and is already initialized as 0, so we're skipping it
   i += 1
   ```

   and then in the rest of the code, use `i + 1` instead of `i` and `i` instead of `i - 1`.
7. The reconstruction loop:

   ```
   i = N
   while i > 0:
       # code
       i -= 1
   ```

   can be written like this:

   ```
   for i in reversed(range(1, N + 1)):
       # code
   ```
8. The code prints an error message like this:

   ```
   print('usage: knapsack.py [file]')
   ```

   Error messages ought to go to standard error (not standard output). And it's a good idea not to hard-code the name of the program, because it would be easy to rename the program but forget to update the code. So write instead:

   ```
   sys.stderr.write("usage: {0} [file]\n".format(sys.argv[0]))
   ```
9. The block of code that reads the problem description and prints the result only runs when `__name__ == '__main__'`. This makes it hard to test, for example from the interactive interpreter. It's usually best to put this kind of code in its own function, like this:

   ```
   def main(filename):
       with open(filename) as f:
           # etc.

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       if len(sys.argv) != 2:
           print('usage: knapsack.py [file]')
           sys.exit(1)
       main(sys.argv[1])
   ```

   and now you can run `main('problem.txt')` from the interpreter to test it.
10. The code reads the whole of the file into memory as a list of lines:

    ```
    lines = f.readlines()
    ```

    this is harmless here because the file is small, but it's usually better to process a file one line at a time, like this:

    ```
    with open(filename) as f:
        maxweight = int(next(f))
        items = [[int(word) for word in line.split()] for line in f]
    ```

#### 2. Recursive approach

Any dynamic programming algorithm can be implemented in two ways: by building a table of partial results from the bottom up (as in the code in the post), or by recursively computing the result from the top down, using [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid computing any partial result more than once.

The top-down approach often results in slightly simpler and clearer code, and it only computes the partial results that are needed for the particular problem instance (whereas in the bottom-up approach it's often hard to avoid computing all partial results even if some of them go unused).

So we could use [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to implement a top-down solution, like this:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def knapsack(items, maxweight):
    """Solve the knapsack problem by finding the most valuable subsequence
    of items that weighs no more than maxweight.

    items must be a sequence of pairs (value, weight), where value is a
    number and weight is a non-negative integer.

    maxweight is a non-negative integer.

    Return a pair whose first element is the sum of values in the most
    valuable subsequence, and whose second element is the subsequence.

    >>> items = [(4, 12), (2, 1), (6, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
    >>> knapsack(items, 15)
    (11, [(2, 1), (6, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2)])

    """
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def bestvalue(i, j):
        # Return the value of the most valuable subsequence of the first
        # i elements in items whose weights sum to no more than j.
        if j < 0:
            return float('-inf')
        if i == 0:
            return 0
        value, weight = items[i - 1]
        return max(bestvalue(i - 1, j), bestvalue(i - 1, j - weight) + value)

    j = maxweight
    result = []
    for i in reversed(range(len(items))):
        if bestvalue(i + 1, j) != bestvalue(i, j):
            result.append(items[i])
            j -= items[i][1]
    result.reverse()
    return bestvalue(len(items), maxweight), result
```

To see how many partial solutions this needs to compute, print `bestvalue.cache_info()` just before returning the result. When solving the example problem in the docstring, this outputs:

```
CacheInfo(hits=17, misses=42, maxsize=None, currsize=42)
```

The 42 entries in the cache are fewer than the 96 partial solutions computed by the bottom up approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response (especially points 3 and 9)! I can't believe I forgot to consider the memoized recursive method. I'll apply some of your suggestions later today, hopefully. Thanks again.

Comment: Beware of recursion depth limit issues with this proposed solution.

Comment: @Frank: yes, this solution uses `len(items)` levels of stack.

Comment: @GarethRees Do you need to define `bestvalue()` inside `knapsack()`? I would tend to avoid defining a function inside a function to make things clearer.

Comment: @greendiod: I defined `bestvalue` inside `knapsack` because (i) it's only used there; (ii) it uses `items` from the outer scope (it would be a pain to have to pass this down through all the recursive calls); (iii) it's memoized so it has an associated cache that we don't want to keep around when `knapsack` has returned.

Comment: ```value, weight = items[i - 1]``` present above the return value of ```bestvalue``` function returns an error: ```ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)```

Comment: @Saurabh: Check your `items` argument: is it a list of pairs as required?

Comment: @GarethRees: Sorry I got the error because I didn't fully implement your review in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

For the first section of code involving nested loops, if you should choose to
 - use `curr` instead of `i`,
 - assign `prev = curr - 1` and
 - use `enumerate(items, 1)`,

the code will literally document itself.

```
for curr, (value, weight) in enumerate(items, 1):
    prev = curr - 1
    for capacity in range(maxweight + 1):
        if weight > capacity:
            bestvalues[curr][capacity] = bestvalues[prev][capacity]
        else:
            candidate1 = bestvalues[prev][capacity]
            candidate2 = bestvalues[prev][capacity - weight] + value

            bestvalues[curr][capacity] = max(candidate1, candidate2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following problem can be solved using *Dynamic Programming* in a much efficient way, in term of lines of code and fastest time to perform computation. On top that , following code perform *memoization* to cache previously computed results.

```
try:
    from functools import lru_cache
except ImportError:
    # For Python2
    # pip install backports.functools_lru_cache
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
class knapsack:
    """
    Maximize sum of selected weight.
    Sum of selected size is less than capacity.
    Algorithm: Dynamic Programming
    ----
    >>>items = [(4, 12), (2, 1), (6, 4), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
    >>>weight, size   = zip(*items)
    >>>weight = list(weight)
    >>>size = list(size)
    >>>capacity = 15
    >>>knapsack(size, weight).solve(capacity)

    >>>(11, [1, 2, 3, 4])

    """
    def __init__(self, size, weight):
        self.size = size
        self.weight = weight
    @lru_cache()
    def solve(self, cap, i=0):
        if cap < 0: return -sum(self.weight), []
        if i == len(self.size): return 0, []
        res1 = self.solve(cap,  i + 1)
        res2 = self.solve(cap - self.size[i], i + 1)
        res2 = (res2[0] + self.weight[i], [i] + res2[1])
        return res1 if res1[0] >= res2[0] else res2
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].